# Trouble with resizing tables - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner with tables so I am having a problem with resizing them. What I have done is if the screen is small, the table content will go under each other. When the screen is bigger, the `width: 100%;` has no effect on the table. I want it to occupy the space like `width: 100%`.

Code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="about.php">About Me</a>
       </td>
       <td>
          <a href="hall-of-fame.php">Hall of Fame</a>
       </td>
       <td>
          <a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: separate;
}
td a{
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ru2fLtn2/)**

If you have an answer/found a mistake in my post/do not understand something or need more details, please reply.

Comment: remove `display: inline-block !important;` https://jsfiddle.net/pno3ftrr/

Comment: Then the content in the Table won't go under each other

Comment: do you mean table cells?

Comment: so replace that with `display: block !important;` .    https://jsfiddle.net/r1a1fgbj/    But then I can't understand why do you need a table

Comment: **Do not use tables for anything other than displaying tabular data!**

Comment: **Do not use !important!**

Comment: I used `!important` because I have other Table styles in my CSS file. I want to keep them as well as use this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a media query for this so that you have more freedom with screen size affecting tables.

https://jsfiddle.net/ru2fLtn2/1/

I simply added the following code...

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  td {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the second `td` CSS code under `@media (max-width: 767px) {` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First and most important:

## Do not use tables for anything other than displaying *tabular data*!

Second:

To fix your issue, add

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

This allows you to define the table width.

Comment: what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

this will prevent the content to have a linebreak

Just add it into your CSS Code into the table element

```
 table {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Comment: No, doesn't solve my problem at all. What I meant is the width of the Table should be 100% (Stretching from Left to right side) but this does not occur when I try the cells to go under each other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line in the td css:

```
    display:inline-block !important;
```

Also, try to avoid !important if you can. See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ru2fLtn2/2/)

Comment: The cells don't go to a new line

Comment: Ah i didn't realize what you were trying to accomplish.  If you want different css for different screen widths, check out bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) - it's almost certainly the most commonly used library for this problem.